# After appending data , the data is not being shown with the class

Tags: jquery

I have got the HTML as above .

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
      <section id="topping_tsection_69">
         <i id="topping-close"></i>
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

When clicked on a button , i am retriving the Topping-details div data as shown .

```
var htmlaaa = $('.activateUiHTML#'+id_attr_val.toString()+' .Topping-details').html();
$("#myordersdiv"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").append(htmlaaa);
```

After appending the data inside myordersdiv , i observe that the section class is not being shown with the class **tpActive** .

Could anybody please help .

Comment: Where id `#myordersdiv`? I must be blind but i can't see it

Comment: you are not appending to myordersdiv, but to myordersdiv+id_attr_val.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use toString() as you did in first line of code:

```
$("#myordersdiv"+id_attr_val.toString()+".Topping-details").append(htmlaaa);
```

Comment: console.log('Kiran'+htmlaaa);  In the console i am getting with  the class tpActive , but after Apending it is not showing with the class tpActive . should i use innerHtml ??

Answer (score 0):

`Id is unique` so do not concatenate for any class  .you have to use directly id   and find the Topping-details to get the relevant html

```
var id="69"; // example 

var data=$("#"+id).find(".Topping-details");

$("#myordersdiv"+id+".Topping-details").append(data);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2u8cK/2/)